# How to read WAL files in pg_xlog directory through java

Tags: java, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Am trying to read WAL files of the postgresql can any body tell me how to do that n what type of binary encoding is used in WAL binary files

Answer (score 6):

You can't really do that. It's easy enough to read the bytes from a WAL archive, but it sounds like you want to *make sense* of them. You will struggle with that.

WAL archives are a binary log showing what blocks changed in the database. They aren't SQL-level or row-level change logs, so you cannot just examine them to get a list of changed rows.

You probably want to investigate trigger-based replication or audit triggers instead.

Answer (score 6):

Using `pg_xlogdump` to read WAL file (this contrib program added to PG 9.3 version - [PG 9.3 released doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/release-9-3.html))

> This utility can only be run by the user who installed the server,
>   because it requires read-only access to the data directory.

```
pg_xlogdump --help
pg_xlogdump decodes and displays PostgreSQL transaction logs for debugging.

Usage:
  pg_xlogdump [OPTION]... [STARTSEG [ENDSEG]]

Options:
  -b, --bkp-details      output detailed information about backup blocks
  -e, --end=RECPTR       stop reading at log position RECPTR
  -f, --follow           keep retrying after reaching end of WAL
  -n, --limit=N          number of records to display
  -p, --path=PATH        directory in which to find log segment files
                         (default: ./pg_xlog)
  -r, --rmgr=RMGR        only show records generated by resource manager RMGR
                         use --rmgr=list to list valid resource manager names
  -s, --start=RECPTR     start reading at log position RECPTR
  -t, --timeline=TLI     timeline from which to read log records
                         (default: 1 or the value used in STARTSEG)
  -V, --version          output version information, then exit
  -x, --xid=XID          only show records with TransactionId XID
  -z, --stats[=record]   show statistics instead of records
                         (optionally, show per-record statistics)
  -?, --help             show this help, then exit
```

For example: `pg_xlogdump  000000010000005A00000096`

[PostgreSQL Document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgxlogdump.html) or [this blog](http://blog.endpoint.com/2016/07/wal-based-estimates-for-when-record-was.html)

Answer (score 3):

The format is complicated and low-level as other answers imply.

However, if you have time to learn and understand the data that is stored, and know how to build the binary from source, there is a published reader for versions `8.3` to `9.2`: [xlogdump](https://github.com/snaga/xlogdump)

The usual way to build it is as a *contrib* (Postgres add-on):

- First get the source for the version of Postgres that you wish to view WAL data for.

  - `./configure` and `make` this, but no need to install
- Then copy the xlogdump folder to the *contrib* folder (a git clone in that folder works fine)
- Run `make` for xlogdump - it should find the parent postgres structure and build the binary

You can copy the binary to your path, or use it in-situ. Be warned, there is still a lot of internal knowledge of Postgres required before you will understand what you are looking at. If you have the database available, it *is* possible to attempt to reverse out SQL statements form the log.

To perform this in Java, you could either wrap the executable, link the C library as a hybrid, or figure out how to do the parsing you need from source. Any of those options are likely to involve a lot of detailed work.

Answer (score 0):

The WAL files are in the same format as the actual database files themselves, and depends on the exact version of PostgreSQL that you are using. You will probably need to examine the source code for your particular version to determine the exact format.

Comment: am using 9.1.6 can you tell me what will be the encoding for that version i tried through java code reading that WAL record file but dint got any thing meaningful

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything specific about the actual PostgreSQL encoding. You will need to do the research yourself.

Comment: @user1802481 The wal files are an postgresql internal format, for which there does not exists a formal specification. Producing a specification for the format from the postgresql code would be dozens, probably hundreds of pages - rather out of scope for an answer of stackoverflow.